Subclass ctypes.c_void_p to represent a custom handler with a custom C function for constructor and destructor / free
I have a somewhat exotic question.
Imagine there is some kind of C interface with ops like (in practice I'm thinking of webrtc vad API):
Handler* create();
int process(Handler*);
void free(Handler*);

I know how to represent these functions using ctypes and ctypes.c_void_p to represent the pointer to a handler.
Now the exotic question. Can one represent this pattern as a class derived from ctypes.c_void_p?

Is it in general correct to derive from ctypes.c_void_p?
Are there any constraints for a constructor of such a derived class? Will the constructor be used by ctypes for constructing marshalled returned handles?
Is it correct to modify the self.value in derived class __init__?
How does ctypes create object of HandlerPointer, will it call the __init__ and will it prevent it from correctly functioning?
Does ctypes support/marshal correctly c_void_p-derived argtypes/restypes?
Is there a more natural way to represent such capsule-like objects (pointer to a possibly opaque structure along with a destructor function) / APIs?

E.g. to do something like:
import os
import ctypes

class HandlerPointer(ctypes.c_void_p):
  @staticmethod
  def ffi(lib_path = os.path.abspath('mylib.so')):
    lib = ctypes.CDLL(lib_path)
    lib.create.argtypes = []
    lib.create.restype = HandlerPointer
    lib.process.argtypes = [HandlerPointer]
    lib.process.restype = ctypes.c_int
    lib.free.argtypes = [HandlerPointer]
    lib.free.restype = None
    return lib

  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.value = self.lib.create().value
  
  def process(self):
    return self.lib.process(self)
  
  def __del__(self):
    self.lib.free(self)

# can't do this var init inside the class as can't refer yet to HandlerPointer inside `.ffi()` if class not initialized yet
HandlerPointer.lib = HandlerPointer.ffi() # otherwise


UPD: it appears that having __init__ method works, except for __del__ method (which calls a C-land custom free method) whose existence will lead to a crash with double free or corruption (!prev). Found the problem, fix described in my comment below, will post a complete solution soon.

Why all the complexity instead of Handler = ctypes.c_void_p?

This was indeed my baseline, and it works well. I was theoretically interested on usage of some sort of derived types of c_void_p to represent this pattern / make clearer ctypes defs and what's ctypes marshaling/object creation behavior for such derived pointer types. It seems it works, at least not segfaults :)

So why not just composition?

Probably I'll revert to the composition baseline, but was wondering whether derivation/inheritance is a supported pattern for this common situation of representing a pointer to an opaque structure with some destructor

It currently appears that __init__ is not used by ctypes and thus can be whatever. However, overriding __del__ to call the native destructor leads to segfault /  double free or corruption (!prev). Not sure why this is.

Found it. It actually happened because __del__ was created on two different instances. To make sure it works, we need to also override __new__ to return an instance from it. I'll post my complete franken-holygrail-stein soon!

If I use ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int16) in arg types. How do I pass in correctly a bytes object? Is ctypes.cast(bytesobj, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int16)) correct? Without an explicit cast I'm getting TypeError: expected LP_c_short instance instead of bytes.

It appears that ctypes bypasses custom-defined __init__ and __new__ when creating c_void_p-derived output objects, so these magics can be safely overridden. And ctypes-based bindings work fine when using ctypes.c_void_p-derived type as part of argtypes/restype. I'm pasting here an example of my bindings for VAD from WebRTC: https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src/+/refs/heads/main which wraps 5 functions (including a constructor and destructor) working with a custom opaque handler:
VadInst* WebRtcVad_Create(void);
void WebRtcVad_Free(VadInst* handle);
int WebRtcVad_Init(VadInst* handle);
int WebRtcVad_set_mode(VadInst* handle, int mode);
int WebRtcVad_Process(VadInst* handle, int fs, const int16_t* audio_frame, size_t frame_length);

This wrapping solution uses:

ctypes.c_void_p-derived class to represent a handler
__new__-magic to bind/represent the factory constructor from the C-land and keep a single Python object ensuring a single-time destruction. This solution would likely lead to crash/double-free if deepcopy is performed on this object (via __del__ being called twice on the same underlying memory-pointer). But I have not tested it.
__init__-magic to represent handler initialization
__del__-magic to call C-land destructor on Python-land object becoming unreferenced

This worked kind of fine if we don't try to deepcopy this handler and trick it into double-free.
# a more complete version at https://github.com/vadimkantorov/webrtcvadctypes

import os
import ctypes

class Vad(ctypes.c_void_p):
    lib_path = os.path.abspath('webrtcvadctypesgmm.so')
    _webrtcvad = None
    
    @staticmethod
    def initialize(lib_path):
        Vad._webrtcvad = Vad.ffi(lib_path)

    @staticmethod
    def ffi(lib_path):
        lib = ctypes.CDLL(lib_path)
        lib.WebRtcVad_Create.argtypes = []
        lib.WebRtcVad_Create.restype = Vad
        lib.WebRtcVad_Free.argtypes = [Vad]
        lib.WebRtcVad_Free.restype = None
        lib.WebRtcVad_Init.argtypes = [Vad]
        lib.WebRtcVad_Init.restype = ctypes.c_int
        lib.WebRtcVad_set_mode.argtypes = [Vad, ctypes.c_int]
        lib.WebRtcVad_set_mode.restype = ctypes.c_int
        lib.WebRtcVad_Process.argtypes = [Vad, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_size_t]
        lib.WebRtcVad_Process.restype = ctypes.c_int
        lib.WebRtcVad_ValidRateAndFrameLength.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_size_t]
        lib.WebRtcVad_ValidRateAndFrameLength.restype = ctypes.c_int
        return lib
    
    @staticmethod
    def valid_rate_and_frame_length(rate, frame_length, lib_path = None):
        if Vad._webrtcvad is None:
            Vad.initialize(lib_path or Vad.lib_path)
        return 0 == Vad._webrtcvad.WebRtcVad_ValidRateAndFrameLength(rate, frame_length)
    
    def set_mode(self, mode):
        assert Vad._webrtcvad is not None
        assert mode in [None, 0, 1, 2, 3]
        if mode is not None:
            assert 0 == Vad._webrtcvad.WebRtcVad_set_mode(self, mode)

    def is_speech(self, buf, sample_rate, length=None):
        assert Vad._webrtcvad is not None
        assert sample_rate in [8000, 16000, 32000, 48000]
        length = length or (len(buf) // 2)
        assert length * 2 <= len(buf), f'buffer has {len(buf) // 2} frames, but length argument was {length}'
        return 1 == Vad._webrtcvad.WebRtcVad_Process(self, sample_rate, buf, length)

    def __new__(cls, mode=None, lib_path = None):
        if Vad._webrtcvad is None:
            Vad.initialize(lib_path or Vad.lib_path)
        assert Vad._webrtcvad is not None
        return Vad._webrtcvad.WebRtcVad_Create()

    def __init__(self, mode=None, lib_path = None):
        assert Vad._webrtcvad is not None
        assert 0 == Vad._webrtcvad.WebRtcVad_Init(self)
        if mode is not None:
            self.set_mode(mode)
    
    def __del__(self):
        assert Vad._webrtcvad is not None
        Vad._webrtcvad.WebRtcVad_Free(self)
        self.value = None


Overall, I'm not sure if representing this semantics via inheritance from c_void_p is the best way, but it was interesting to play with this and various related Python magic methods.
